# How to maintain history data whose schema changes quarterly using Hadoop

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, hadoop, talend

I have json input file which stores survey data(feedback from the customers).

- The columns in json file can vary

  for e.g. in first quarter there can
  be 70 columns and in next quarter it can have 100 columns and so on.
- I want to store all this quarterly data in same table on hdfs.

Is there a way to maintain history either by drop and re-creating the table with changing schema?

How will it behave if the column length goes down let's say in 3rd quarter we get only 30 columns.

Answer (score 0):

First point is that in HDFS you don't store tables just files. You create tables in hive impala etc. on top of files.

Some of the formats support schema merging at read, for example [parquet](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-parquet.html#schema-merging)
In general you will be able to recreate your table with a super-set of columns. In Impala you have similar capabilities for [schema evolution](https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-9-x/topics/impala_parquet.html#parquet_schema_evolution).